# What musical version of Cinderella did I see on television?

Tags: story-identification, movie, cinderella

I remember watching a musical version of "Cinderella" on television in the 1980s, although it was unquestionably older than that.  It was a feature-length presentation, in color, and I had long assumed that it was one of the versions of *[Rodgers & Hammerstein's Cinderella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinderella_(musical))*.  However, when I looked at the song list for that version, it did not agree with what I remember seeing.

I do not actually remember that much about what I saw, except for one particular scene.  The prince and his best friend are in the palace, discussing how regimented the prince's life is, by the nature of his station.  They wander into the family white-walled crypt, where the prince points out that he even has a tomb already prepared for him when he dies.  At this point, the two men burst into song, something about "a ready-made place in the family space," while (and this is the part that was especially memorable) doing gymnastics all around the crypt, including swinging from the rafters.

After this scene, the prince happens to see Cinderella from a distance, as he has been sitting sadly in a nearby field and picking flowers.  This is the first time he has seen her, and he is quite taken, but she runs away, and they do not speak.

I do not recall much more.  There was the ball, with plenty of songs, and I think I did not actually see the end.  I looked at the long list of adaptations of "Cinderella" on IMDB, but I could not find any that matched—a live-action musical, in color, in English.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Possibly *[The Slipper and the Rose](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Slipper_and_the_Rose)*?

> Whilst putting flowers by her parents' grave, [Cinderella] inadvertently stumbles upon the prince, and his friend and bodyguard John, who are visiting the Royal crypt. The Prince sardonically talks about his dead ancestors, with whom he will one day be buried ("What a Comforting Thing to Know").

This would appear to be the song you're remembering:

[It includes the lines:](https://genius.com/Christopher-gable-what-a-comforting-thing-to-know-annotated)

> What a comforting thing to know /
>   There's a prearranged spot in the family plot /
>   Where my royal bones will go /
>   Yes, I'll be slipped into the beautiful family crypt

so you weren't far off.